# After cloning, the system Windows 8.1 shows the size of the smaller disk

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-8, partitioning, dd

I have ask a related question [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330417/cloning-the-d-disk-how-do-i-recognize-the-right-if-dev). I have cloned 4TB HDD onto 8.TB but the
system (Win 8.1) shows the size of the lower of the 2 disks, i.e. the size of the source while cloning.
How do I assign the entire space to my new large 8TB disk ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cloning made an *exact copy* of the 4 TB HDD. That would leave unused the other ~4 TB of the larger HDD. In Ubuntu, [open the *Disks* utility application](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/manage-ubuntu-hdd-disk-utility/) to view and to expand the 4 TB partition, likely formatted as *ext4*, to include the unused space.

Likely, you will need to boot from another drive to perform that operation, since the system mounts the HDD, and the operation must be performed on an unmounted disk.  The easiest way to do this is to boot from a [Ubuntu Live USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) device, since that also includes *Disks*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to shrink the partition in Disk Management for a bit. It should update the metadata of the filesystem. Once it's proper, you can extend it again.

If you did a full disk clone then you probably only need to extend. The above was for a partition clone.